# possible to style link rel?

Tags: html, css

This is probably a stupid question but I'll chance it anyways...

I've got something like...

```
<link rel='next' title='a title!' href='http://alink.com' />
```

I'm wondering is it possible for me to style all link rel's with 'next' in an external stylesheet?

Comment: And where would you like to see the result of the styling? element link doesn't render anything. Do you perhaps mean the anchor tag `a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you're using `link` right? See the [spec here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.3). A `<link>` tag is only specified in the head of the document and isn't rendered. You might be thinking of anchor (`<a/>`) tags.

You can specify a CSS [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs):

```
a[rel=next] { color: blue; }
```

---

Since IE6 doesn't support the attribute selector, you have a couple of options for complete compatibility. You could just hand code the class of the anchor or use JavaScript.

Here's a JavaScript solution using jQuery (similar syntax), but it's probably not the most ideal for just IE6 and below:

```
$("a[rel=next]").addClass("myRelClass");
```

Comment: What browsers will this NOT work in? I am assuming IE6 will fail hard. Awesome to know though, I didn't know the existence of that selector.

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html, it's IE5.5 and IE6. The rest seem compatible

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is an anchor tag, not a link tag. And if so, then you can use the following CSS

```
a[rel='next'] { color: red; }
a[rel='prev'] { color: green; }
```

to style

```
<a rel='next' title='a title!' href='http://alink.com' >Next</a>
<a rel='prev' title='a title!' href='http://alink.com' >Previous</a>
```

[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/yqptc/)

Answer (score 0):

In regular webbrowsers this `<link>` doesn't have any visible representation, so how could you  style it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like the following in your external CSS file...

```
link[rel=next] {
   color: red;
}
```

BTW: You probably mean the HTML-tag `<a>` e.g. `<a href="http://domain.tld">Link</a>`